# Learning React: why do we not have to use this.state.count in line 18 to access the count but we have to use this.state.imageUrl in line 12?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm not sure why the output disappears if I do this.state.count in line 18 instead. Would appreciate the help

```
  export default class Counter extends Component {
  state = {
    count: 0,
    imageUrl: "https://picsum.photos/200"
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
    <img src={this.state.imageUrl} alt="" />
    <span>{this.formatCount()}</span>
        <button>Increment</button>
      </div>
    );
  }

  formatCount() {
    const { count } = this.state;
    return count === 0 ? "Zero" : count;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do:

```
const { count } = this.state;
```

You extract `count` from `this.state`, it's called destructuring

You could also have it this way:

```
formatCount() {
    return this.state.count === 0 ? "Zero" : this.state.count;
}
```

Comment: ah makes sense, is it because of the curly braces when we do const { count } = this.state;

Comment: Yes, you could also do `const { imageUrl, count } = this.state` to extract more than one property from an object

Comment:  I just want to mention another shorthand is by using get proprty  `get count(){ return this.state/count}`

Answer (score 0):

this `const { count } = this.state;` called  destructuring and it been add to javascript on es2015 version

you can set new variable name for proprty like this

`const { count:value } = this.state;`

and you set initial value in case the object value is undefined

`const { count=0 } = this.state;`

you can create a get proprty as shorthand for `this.state.count` like this

```js
export default class Counter extends Component {
  state = {
    count: 0,
    imageUrl: "https://picsum.photos/200"
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div> 
    {this.count} 
    <img src={this.state.imageUrl} alt="" />
    <span>{this.formatCount()}</span>
        <button>Increment</button>
      </div>
    );
  }

  formatCount() {
    return count === 0 ? "Zero" : count;
  }

 get count(){
  return this.state.count;
 }
```

read  [MDN destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) explain the all destructuring feature.